# Use pdf.js in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf

I've downloaded the [pdf.js extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) to Firefox. But when I open a PDF file, it is still displayed using Adobe Reader. How can I have it displayed using pdf.js?

Comment: Doesn't Firefox 21 come with it by default?

Comment: Yes, it comes with it.

Comment: @Paul, go to Addons -> plugins -> Disable the plugin Adobe reader their.

Comment: @F1beta Yes, that works! Do you want to make it an answer? I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tried this

Go to Firefox -> Tools -> Add-ons -> plugin -> Disable the plugin Adobe reader here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that following this instructions :
Firefox -> Options -> Applications -> Adobe Acrobat Document then set the default program.

Good Luck.